# How to use <br> tag in bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to break the line after Other online payment. but when I added `<br>` tag this starts making problems in the card content alignment. I'm using bootstrap. any idea why? thank you :)

```css
.user-ads {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -55px;
}

.user-ads li {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.user-ads li span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card" style="width: 32rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <ul class="user-ads">
      <li><strong>Seller </strong><span>tempestblaze</span></li>
      <li><strong>Payment method </strong><span><a href="">Other online payment:</a> Koho App</span></li>
      <li><strong>Price/BTC </strong><span>1,233,775.89 PKR</span></li>
      <li><strong>Limits </strong><span>10,000 - 62,538 PKR</span></li>
      <li><span><a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Buy</a></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I added a second break to prevent errors with overflow messing up your margins. I tested this on my on server and it looks good. Kudos!

```
<div class="card" style="width: 32rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="user-ads">
          <li><strong>Seller </strong><span>tempestblaze</span></li>
          <li><strong>Payment method </strong><span><a href="">Other online payment:</a><br> Koho App</span></li>
          <br>
          <li><strong>Price/BTC </strong><span>1,233,775.89 PKR</span></li>
          <li><strong>Limits </strong><span>10,000 - 62,538 PKR</span></li>
          <li><span><a class="btn btn-primary" href="">Buy</a></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```